# How to send data to server from angularjs

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, spring

I am trying to send data to server using $http.post(). I wrote some code but it shows nothing. I just want to send a string variable and print it from a java page.

```
<body ng-controller="HelloCtrl">    
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
    app.controller("HelloCtrl", function($scope, $http) {   
        $scope.name="Subhajyoti";           
        $scope.showName= function(){
            $http.post('insertEntry',$scope.name)
            .success(function(data){
                alert(data);
            })
            .error(function(data){
                alert("Error");
            })
        }
    });
 </script>
</body>
```

This is my java page code..

```
@Controller
public class Rules {
@RequestMapping(value="insertEntry", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String insertEntry(@RequestParam String name){
    String val=name;
    System.out.println(val);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    String message = "Success";

    json.put("message", message);
    return json.toString();
}
```

}

I am interacting angularjs with spring mvc. please help me with example. I am new to it.

Comment: make sure to put url not only insertEntry

Comment: What  angularJS version you are using? 
The `.success` and `.error` are deprecated.

Comment: please help me with the java page coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insertEntry")
```

And

```
$http.post('/insertEntry')
```

Check one [tutorial](http://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/angularjs-http-service-ajax-post-code-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
   <html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
        app.controller("HelloCtrl", function($scope, $http) {   
            $scope.name="Subhajyoti";           
               $http.post('/insertEntry', {name:$scope.name}).
          then(function(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
          }, function(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
          }); 
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body >  
 <div data-ng-app="MyApp"
        ng-controller="HelloCtrl">

    </body>
</html>
```

And modify your `Controller` class as below:

```
@Controller
public class Rules {
@RequestMapping(value="insertEntry", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String insertEntry(@RequestBody String name){
    String val=name;
    System.out.println(val);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    String message = "Success";

    json.put("message", message);
    return "".toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, how you are calling ` $scope.showName` before, try now as mentioned in answer!

Comment: I just did the same as u say @Arpit.

Comment: If I just call http.post and wite a java page like that. is it enough? i mean how they will interact? is program counter is going to that java function?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code where I call the server.
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

```
    app.controller("JsonCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

        var dataObj = {
                "ruleId" : "1234",
                "version" : "R1234",
                "name" : "Usage crossing 50MB",
                "description" : "Find usage more than 50mb",
                "active" : true,
                "created_by" : "Rahul",
                "create_date" : "2015-08-18",
                "modified_date" : "2015-08-22",
                "modified_by" : "Subho"
            };

        var response = $http.post('PostService', dataObj);
        response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.responseData = data;
        });
        response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({
                data : data
            }));
        });

    });
```

The server page code:

```
 @Controller
  public class JsonServer {
@RequestMapping(value = "/PostService", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody String PostService(@RequestBody RuleModel m) {

    StringBuilder reponseData = new StringBuilder();
    reponseData.append("RuleID: "+m.getRuleId()+" ");
    reponseData.append("version: "+m.getVersion()+" ");
    reponseData.append("name: "+m.getName()+" ");
    reponseData.append("description: "+m.getDescription()+" ");
    reponseData.append("created_by: "+m.getCreated_by()+" ");
    reponseData.append("create_date: "+m.getCreate_date()+" ");
    reponseData.append("modified_date: "+m.getModified_date()+" ");
    reponseData.append("modified_by: "+m.getModified_by()+" ");
    reponseData.append("category_name: "+m.getCategory_name()+" ");

    return reponseData.toString();
}
}
```